# Alignment of colorbar with colorbar to name

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

I am trying to make a group of plots with `groupplots` sharing the same `colorbar` and the same y axis. An example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
point meta min=0, point meta max=25,
group style={group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left, ylabels at=edge left,
},
colorbar,
colorbar to name=commonbar,
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{commonbar}
\end{document}
```

Here, the `colorbar to name` option takes care of using the same `colorbar` for all plots (there is a warning from pdflatex on "multiply defined labels" -- to be expected, I suppose, and no problem as long as the range of the `colorbar` is specified). The `colorbar` is then "placed" by the `\ref{commonbar}` command.

How can I align the `colorbar` properly with the figures? I have tried placing the `\ref` command in several places (the placement above gives the best result I've seen so far). You may say I'm looking for the equivalent of `yticklabels at=edge left` for colorbars.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning about the multiply defined labels comes from the fact that you supplied the `colorbar to name` key to the `groupplot` environment, which in turn applies it to each of the plots in the group, so it is executed twice in this case. If you just supply `colormap` to the last `\nextgroupplot[<options>]`, the message will disappear and the colormap will be placed as desired, without using `colorbar to name` and `\ref`. If you do want to use `colormap to name`, Percusse's answer is a good way to go.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
    point meta min=0, point meta max=25,
    group style={
        group size=2 by 1,
        yticklabels at=edge left,
        ylabels at=edge left
    }
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\nextgroupplot[colorbar]
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the type of solution I was looking for! Does this mean that all (or perhaps a large, meaningful subset) of the options that can be applied to the `axis` environments also can be applied to `\nextgroupplot`?

Comment: @JosteinBøFløystad: Yes, all the options that can be supplied to an `axis` can also be applied to `nextgroupplot`. The `groupplots` environment is basically an elaborate wrapper for several full-fledged `axis` environments.

Answer (score 6):

This just works and there is manual adjustment involved. Probably, Christian or Jake would give you an automated solution. I put the `commonbar` into a node and placed it next to the rightmost groupplot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
point meta min=0, point meta max=25,
group style={group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left, ylabels at=edge left,
},
colorbar,
colorbar to name={commonbar},
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\end{groupplot}
\node[anchor=west,inner sep=0] at([shift={(5mm,0cm)}]group c2r1.east) {\ref{commonbar}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For some reason the labels of the colorbar moves too close to the colormap.  <strike>I don't know why exactly this is happening.But I'll look into it.</strike>  I used `inner sep=0` and that is inherited by `colormap`. Removing that option fixes that problem.

Answer (score 3):

[Percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52135/alignment-of-colorbar-with-colorbar-to-name/52144#52144) helped me a lot, but the colorbar was not placed perfectly aligned to my plot. I made a slight modification, which works without using an extra `\node` and without static widths. This is done by placing the colorbar with `colorbar style`. The colorbar is finally displayed by `\pgfplotscolorbarfromname{commonbar}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
point meta min=0, point meta max=25,
group style={group size=2 by 1,
    yticklabels at=edge left, ylabels at=edge left,
},
colorbar,
colorbar to name={commonbar},
colorbar style={
    at={(group c2r1.north east)},
    anchor=north west
}
]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot[scatter, scatter src=y] {x^2};
\end{groupplot}
\pgfplotscolorbarfromname{commonbar}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I would have made a comment, but I have not enough reputation to do so.